# MySQL Database - Importing 1Million entries

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I have a csv file that has over 1Million rows. The file is 37Mb roughly, where phpmyadmin says it can be up to 300MB. I try to import this large file into a PhpMyAdmin/MySql database. It loads the file, then brings me to "[phpMyAdminroot]/import.php" with a blank page. Nothing happens after this. No table has been inserted.

I assume this is due to the huge number of rows. 
I guess my question is, how can I insert these desired rows into a new table on the database?

Edit 1
I am unable to access the database remotely, only through the provided hosting service's phpMyAdmin

Comment: How are you inserting them, exactly? Is splitting your CSV up into smaller chunks an option?

Comment: white page in php = something blew up, and all debug options are turned off. turn on error_reporting and display_errors at the php.ini level, and try again

Comment: That's quite large for PHPMyAdmin. Have you considered a command line tool such as mysqlimport - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html

Comment: I am using the import area in PhpMyAdmin. 
Enabled "Do not abort on INSERT error"
Splitting the CSV up is an option, however I am reluctant on taking that option if the chunks have to be so small that there will be just too many chunks.

Comment: What is "too many"? A few thousand small chunks of a few thousand rows you can load in using a simple script is better than one big file you can't import.

Comment: @tadman How would one split into these chunks and load them into a db?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using MysqlWorkbench, I've had a similar problem and Workbench is able to import bigger files. As to why it doesn't work, I've also seen phpmyadmin stop when the execute time takes too long, maybe it's that but it's just not throwing an error?

Comment: I am unable to access the database remotely, only able to access through the hosting services phpmyadmin

Comment: So you don't have acces to php.ini, ... files?
If thats the problem things are going to be hard to debug. No error_reporting, changing configuration, ...
You could ask your hosting company to change some things in the php.ini to increase file upload.

Comment: No access to any of those files unfortunately. I will look into contacting the hosting company if I have no luck with other solutions

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an application called [Excel2MySQL](http://excel2mysql.net).  It supports the Excel maximum sheet size which is 1,048,576 rows and 16,384 columns.  I am currently working on adding support for CSV import as well, so that it can handle many millions of records.  Currently it imports directly from Excel and more importantly, it will accurately import your data and handle table creation and field optimization.

Most modern providers allow you to add your local ip address to an "allow-access list" which you can do yourself through something like a [cPanel](http://cpanel.net/). Then you can access your MySQL database through standard tcpip port 3306.  Keep in mind that your remote ip address may change from time to time and you will have to add the new ip address to the access list from time to time.  Here's one way to find your [ip-address](http://www.hostgator.com/ip).  Here is my host provider's [documentation](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/how-to-connect-to-the-mysql-database-remotely) on remote MySQL connection.

Check carefully with your MySQL database service provider.  Once you've added you ip to a white-list, you can access your MySQL server with other great tools like [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/)... etc.